# DataFrame: how can I groupby Z and calculate the mean X in Y range

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame which includes 3 columns - `Test`, `X` and `Y`. I want to add new columns `Xmean` which include the mean value of `X` with a condition on `Y` for each `Test`.

For example `Xmean` include the mean value on `X` while `Y >= 5` for each `Test`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv(r'Downloads\test.txt',delimiter=',',encoding='utf-8')

df_sort=df.sort_values("test")

df_filter=df_sort[df_sort['y']>=5]

## applying aggregates function to find mean

df_agg=df_filter.groupby(['test'])['x'].mean()

## join two dataframes to get desired output

df_final=pd.merge(df_sort[['test','x','y']],df_agg,on='test')

print(df_final)

[Output attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmsoV.png)